# Error al compilar aplicación

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Estoy queriendo compilar pero me salen los siguientes errores.

He tratado diferentes métodos de solución, incluso borrar del disco, los archivos duplicados, pero sin éxito.

```
C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\0cb9ff486f5edb59977e253831b932c8\appcompat-1.2.0\res\values\values.xml:1692:5-1774:25: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/background' with config ''.

C:\Users\ADMIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\0cb9ff486f5edb59977e253831b932c8\appcompat-1.2.0\res\values\values.xml:1692:5-1774:25: AAPT: error: resource previously defined here.

C:\Users\ADMIN\AndroidStudioProjects\qremote\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.
```

comparto detalle de build.gradle

```
plugins { 
id 'com.android.application'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    google()
}
android {

    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.lge.qremote"
        minSdkVersion 29
        //noinspection ExpiredTargetSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
   
 implementation ('com.jcodecraeer:xrecyclerview:1.5.8'){
        exclude group:'com.android.support'
    }
}
```

Este es el build.gradle en mi proyecto.
He tratado diferentes métodos de solución, incluso borrar del disco, los archivos duplicados, pero sin éxito.

Comment: Probablemente es un error en alguna de las dependencias de tu proyecto. Sería de ayuda que muestres tu archivo `build.gradle` (el del módulo)

Comment: a continuacion el build.gradle

Comment: Para qué es `com.jcodecraeer:xrecyclerview`? Funciona si lo eliminas?

Comment: `com.android.support:multidex` está obsoleto. Deberías eliminarlo o usar la versión androidx